Qt incomplete type is not allowed
I am trying to make a simple GUI in qt. I want to have a ChooseModeGUI window, where I can pick (click 1 of 2 buttons) and choose a mode.
The files that I have are:
ChooseModeGUI.ui 
AdministratorGUI.ui
UserGUI.ui

ChooseModeGUI.h
AdministratorGUI.h
UserGUI.h

ChooseModeGUI.cpp
AdministratorGUI.cpp
UserGUI.cpp

I have this error in ChooseModeGUI.cpp: "incomplete type is not allowed". This error is in line 6, mainly the "ui(new Ui::ChooseModeGUI)" part. How can I fix this?
The code from the ChooseModeGUI.h:
h_code
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qlistwidget.h>
#include <qlineedit.h>
#include <qlabel.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>
#include "GUI/Source/Headers/AdministratorGUI.h"
#include "GUI/Source/Headers/UserGUI.h"
#include "Controller/Controller.h"
#include "string"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class ChooseModeGUI; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class ChooseModeGUI : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QLabel* label;
    QPushButton* userModeButton;
    QPushButton* administratorModeButton;

public:
    explicit ChooseModeGUI(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

private:
    Ui::ChooseModeGUI* ui;
    void UserModeButtonHandler();
    void AdministratorModeButtonHandler();
};

And here is the code from the ChooseModeGUI.cpp:
cpp_code
#include "GUI/Source/Headers/ChooseModeGUI.h"
#include "QMessageBox"
#include "ui_ChooseModeGUI.h"

ChooseModeGUI::ChooseModeGUI(QWidget* parent) :
    QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::ChooseModeGUI)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}


void ChooseModeGUI::UserModeButtonHandler()
{

}

void ChooseModeGUI::AdministratorModeButtonHandler()
{

}


Code that you want us to consider should be included as text and in the question itself.

Please [edit] your question to include all code as text (no links or images) -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].  Likewise, all error messages should be shown as text verbatim.

The code from the ChooseModeGUI.h, And here is the code from the ChooseModeGUI.cpp I don't see the code that can be compiled. I see the links to pictures that can't be compiled.

OT: #include "string" should be #include <string> with the "" you likely (implementation defined behavior) tell the compiler to look in the same folder of your cpp source files for a string header. When the compiler doesn't find it there it will look in your system locations.

What is in ui_ChooseModeGUI.h?

This ...

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
    namespace Ui { class ChooseModeGUI; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE


... forward declares a class named QT_NAMESPACE::Ui::ChooseModeGui, where QT_NAMESPACE is a macro that may expand to nothing.  Note that the namespace declaration's scope encompasses just that declaration.
This ...

class ChooseModeGUI : public QWidget
{
   // ...
}


..., not being inside the namespace declaration, defines a class in the global namespace.  Its qualified name is ::ChooseModeGUI.  This is a different class from QT_NAMESPACE::Ui::ChooseModeGui and Ui::ChooseModeGui, which may also be different from each other, so when you attempt to instantiate Ui::ChooseModeGui, that type is still incomplete.  This is the issue.
You should not be putting your own classes into the Qt namespace anyway, so what you're probably looking for in your header is (header inclusions, plus ...):
namespace Ui {

class ChooseModeGUI : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QLabel* label;
    QPushButton* userModeButton;
    QPushButton* administratorModeButton;

public:
    explicit ChooseModeGUI(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

private:
    ChooseModeGUI* ui;
    void UserModeButtonHandler();
    void AdministratorModeButtonHandler();
};

}

That declares and defines type Ui::ChooseModeGUI. No need for a separate forward declaration.  Note that the class definition is inside the namespace declaration.

Addendum
It was suggested in comments that you might intend two ChooseModeGui classes, one in the global namespace and one in the Ui namespace.  In that event,

Don't do that.  At minimum, use two different named namespaces, and avoid putting your own classes in the global namespace.

You might (or might not) need to take the suggested code more as a general model of how to define a class in a named namespace than as a directly usable substitute for what you have now.

Other than that, all of the above still applies.



This answer is plausible, but there is one detail from the question that sticks out to me: the line #include "ui_ChooseModeGUI.h", which is done in addition to #include "GUI/Source/Headers/ChooseModeGUI.h". This suggests to me that maybe there are supposed to be two ChooseModeGUI classes -- one inside the Ui namespace and one outside.

@JaMiT, the first part of this answer responds directly to the question actually posed, answering it even in the event that the OP actually does intend there to be two ChooseModeGUI classes in different namespaces.  The diagnostic presented makes sense only if there is a forward declaration of Ui::ChooseModeGui as a class or struct, without a definition.  In the unlikely event that the OP actually does want two classes with the same name, in different namespaces, then they might or might not want the exact mitigation suggested, but it's a useful model in any case.

Note that "ui_*.h" are autogenerated files by Qt's User Interface Compiler, which automatically places those auto-generated classes in a Ui namespace.

I can't speak directly to the behavior of the Qt uic, @m7913d, but clearly the ui_ChooseModeGUI.h that the OP is working with, wherever it came from, does not define a class named Ui::ChooseModeGUI.
